# How can I change column headers in tables/pivot tables in icCube reporting v6?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Is it possible to change the column headers of tables/pivot tables? By default they are named as the hierarchy/measure.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use **icCube Table's Cell Renderers**  to do that.

Cell renderers is a powerful feature of icCube tables, that provides a bunch of opportunities to configure look & feel of your tables.

It can be found under "Data Render Options" category of widget options.

### Several Cell Renderers

If you have static order of columns in your table you can create cell renderers for each column bound by it's index:

First column:
[image]

Second column:
[image]

### One Cell Renderer / Javascript Way

This is a dynamic solution and doesn't depend on columns order.

You might want to use "Top Header Text" field to overwrite header label as shown in the picture below:
[image]

In this case I've created an alias for header labels with this peace of javascript code:

[image]

This solution an code could be expanded to handle as many columns as you need.

**P.S.**

"Top Header Text" field's expression value suitable for your case:

```
var header = context.columnLabel()

switch(header){
    case 'formatted_date_hierarchy': return 'Date';
    case 'product_hierarchy': return 'Product';
    default: return header;
}
```

### UPDATE

Here is a [Demo Report](https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FTable%20Headers%20Labels%20%26%20Hooks%20example&mode=editing_reporting&ic3demo) with first solution.